# node.js express.js routes slash css

Tags: html, node.js, express

when i write localhost/profil the css works.
But when i write localhost/profil/ the css doesn't work.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
app.get('/profil',[checkCo],require('./routes/profil.js'));
```

Why?

thanks!

**edit:**

it's because it thinks that profil/ is a folder, so how can i get around this?

Comment: why is this a problem for you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You likely need to use absolute paths within your HTML.

For example, instead of

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

you need to do

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
```

In the first example, the browser tries to access `style.css` in the current directory the user is navigated to. So if the user is navigated to `/profil/`, it tries to load the css from `/profil/style.css`. In the second example, the browser is told to load the css from `/style.css` no matter what.

Comment: @CydGy Remember to accept answers (check the tick next to them) if you've gotten what you need.